# How to build lemmatizer using Fasttext

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lemmatization, fasttext

I have a huge amount of words (4M) in Arabic dialect with their correspending lemmas and i want to build a lemmatizer for new words not in that data by leveraging it. The question is how to use FastText to build this lemmatizer?

Answer (score 0):

I think that fasttext isn't useful for the lemmatization task: word embedding has no grammatical knowledge of words in the corpus.

Instead, you should consider using classical NLP libraries, such as Spacy or NLTK.